# How to put a letter instead a number when numbering results using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script to number strings results, but I'd like to use a letter instead a number, how can I do it?

```
<span id="posicao"></span>

// numera questões
$("*[id*=posicao]").each(function(index) {
    $(this).append("Questão " + (index + 1));
});
```

e.g:

Tick a fruit:

```
1. Car  
2. ball   
2. orange   
4. cell
```

I'd like:

```
A. Car  
B. ball   
C. orange   
D. cell
```

Comment: You can do this with an ordered list and css, using `list-style-type: upper-latin;`

Comment: @Kobe how to use ordered list with letter?

Comment: See my answer @MiguelSilva

Comment: @Kobe you're right, I've forgot that. thanks man!

Comment: @MiguelSilva No problem, things like that are often forgetful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should incorporate using a list in your HTML instead. You can use an ordered list, replace your `span`s with `li`s and style `list-style-type` as such:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-latin;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ol>
```

There is no need to over complicate anything with JS.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="posicao"></div>

var littersArr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
$(".posicao").each(function (index) {
    $(this).append(littersArr[index] + '.' + "string");
});
```

Comment: What if the length of  `posicao` is more than 26?

Comment: in this case my answer is wrong and use another like
<style>
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-latin;
}
</style>
<ol>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ol>

Answer (score -1):

In terms of keeping your code very similar, you can simply use an array of letters:

```js
var letters = ['A','B','C','D'];

// numera questões
$("*[id*=posicao]").each(function(index) {
    $(this).append("Questão " + letters[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="posicao"></span>
<span id="posicao"></span>
<span id="posicao"></span>
<span id="posicao"></span>
```

Alternatively a better option might be to use an ordered list and CSS

```css
ol li{
list-style-type: upper-latin;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```